# #pine script strategy The 'resolution' argument is incompatible with functions that have side effects

Tags: pine-script

I am new in pine coding,and now I just want to do some simple strategy from one genious editor

```
study("RedK Slow_Smooth WMA", shorttitle="RSS_WMA v2", overlay = true, resolution = "") 

//===============================================
f_LazyLine(_data, _length) =>
    w1 = 0, w2 = 0, w3 = 0
    L1 = 0.0, L2 = 0.0, L3 = 0.0
    w = _length / 3
    
    if _length > 2 
        w2 := round(w)
        w1 := round((_length-w2)/2)
        w3 :=   int((_length-w2)/2)
        
        L1 := wma(_data, w1)
        L2 := wma(L1, w2)
        L3 := wma(L2, w3)
    else
        L3 := _data
    L3
//====================================


price       = input(title = "Source",                 type = input.source,  defval = close)
alpha       = input(title = "Combined Smoothness",    type = input.integer, defval = 15, minval = 1)

LL = f_LazyLine(price, alpha)

c_up        = color.new(#33ff00, 0)
c_dn        = color.new(#ff1111, 0)
uptrend     = LL > LL[1]

plot(LL,                "SS_WMA Line",  color = uptrend ? c_up : c_dn,  linewidth=3)
plot(wma(price, alpha), "WMA",          color = color.purple,           display=0)

if (LL > LL[1])
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long)
    if (LL < LL[1])
        strategy.close_all()
if (LL < LL[1])
    strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short)
    if (LL > LL[1])
        strategy.close_all()
```

However it shows : The 'resolution' argument is incompatible with functions that have side effects
Anyone knows where I can correct my code??
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Strategy calls (`strategy.entry()`) cannot be used in study/indicator scripts.
   If you want to write a strategy you should write instead of

```
study("RedK Slow_Smooth WMA", shorttitle="RSS_WMA v2", overlay = true, resolution = "")
```

use this

```
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)
```

2.If you want to use data values from different `resolution` than in the current chart, you should use `security` function.

For now you can run your strategy by copying this code:

```
//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

f_LazyLine(_data, _length) =>
    w1 = 0, w2 = 0, w3 = 0
    L1 = 0.0, L2 = 0.0, L3 = 0.0
    w = _length / 3
    
    if _length > 2 
        w2 := round(w)
        w1 := round((_length-w2)/2)
        w3 :=   int((_length-w2)/2)
        
        L1 := wma(_data, w1)
        L2 := wma(L1, w2)
        L3 := wma(L2, w3)
    else
        L3 := _data
    L3
//====================================


price       = input(title = "Source",                 type = input.source,  defval = close)
alpha       = input(title = "Combined Smoothness",    type = input.integer, defval = 15, minval = 1)

LL = f_LazyLine(price, alpha)

c_up        = color.new(#33ff00, 0)
c_dn        = color.new(#ff1111, 0)
uptrend     = LL > LL[1]

plot(LL,                "SS_WMA Line",  color = uptrend ? c_up : c_dn,  linewidth=3)
plot(wma(price, alpha), "WMA",          color = color.purple,           display=0)

if (LL > LL[1])
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long)
    if (LL < LL[1])
        strategy.close_all()
if (LL < LL[1])
    strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short)
    if (LL > LL[1])
        strategy.close_all()
```

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Strategies.html